# Wifi Hardware Blocked on Lenovo G50-30

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, lenovo, ideapad

I own a *Lenovo G50-30* with Ubuntu 14.04 (x32). I have a problem with my wifi.

When I tried:

```
 sudo rfkill list
```

get Result as,

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN 
     Soft blocked: no 
     Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth 
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: yes
```

Even though it shows Bluetooth HardBlocked,Bluetooth functions as normal....

I checked the Harware Switch, it is OK. I am using Wireless connection in Windows.

Any soluton??

Comment: Did you tried to unblock the device? Or with another module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your wireless come to life if you unload a module?

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

If this helps, we'll blacklist the module.

Comment: I think it should be `ideapad_laptop`.  That's how it appears on my Lenovo Legion laptop.

Comment: @mwcz They are equivalent. Check: `modinfo ideapad_laptop` produces the same output as `modinfo ideapad-laptop` and doesn't produce any errors.